# WP_Query to get post on frontpage

Tags: wp-query, theme-development

I've been working on my frontpage for a website, and now, at the bottom I want to add another post, outside the main loop, to this page.

I've used a WP_Query:

```
$args = array( 
        'post_type'   => 'post',
        'tag_id'      => '32'
    );


    $fp_post = new WP_Query( $args );

    if($fp_post->have_posts()) :
        while ($fp_post->have_posts()) : $fp_post->the_post();
            the_content();
        endwhile;
    else:
        echo 'its not working';
    endif;
```

Now, I get back that it's not working, but I'm sure there is a post with an id of 32. This should mean my array is empty, but I don't know why this is. Did I make some basic mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get a post with the id of *32*, the parameter you would use is `p`, which is one of the [Post & Page Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters). `tag_id` is used for querying posts with a particular [Tag ID](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters).

```
$args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'p'         => 32
);

$fp_post = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $fp_post->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $fp_post->have_posts() ) : $fp_post->the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
else:
        echo 'it is not working';
endif;
```

Comment: You got it, Rik!